# Big O complexity , multiple for loops

Tags: big-o

I have written a simple algorithm to re-order the items in a list whenever the user drag and drop them. Also, if an item is deleted or a now one is added the list will be re-ordered. The algorithm contains three separated linear for loops (each one of them is O(n) ) and has two nested loops ( O(n^2) ). Is the total complexity O( n+ n +n + n^2) = O (3n+ n^2)?

How can I calculate the total big O ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks good. If it's correct, you can get better: `O(3n+n^2) == O(n^2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`O(3n + n^2)` is the same thing as `O(n^2)`.

[Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation only describes limiting behavior, and both functions have the same limiting behavior -- doubling `n` quadruples them. (As `n` goes to infinity, the `3n` component becomes smaller and smaller relative to the `n^2` component. At the limit, it completely dominates it.)

Comment: Could we say that the term with the largest exponent overrides all other terms as a general rule?

Comment: @cbaby we could, but only if all terms are some powers of x

Comment: @cbaby It's not true that `O(2^x+x^2) = O(x^2)`

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, but you can't explicitly say 2 is greater then x in asymptotic analysis either :)

Comment: @cbaby what about this? `O(x^2+(x^1.5)^1.5)`? `2>1.5`

Comment: @JanDvorak well that example is sort of notation abusing, you could write it like `O(x*x+(x^1.5)^1.5)` or `O(x^2+x^2.25)` it doesn't change the fact that `2<2.25`. I see what you are trying to do there, but I think there is no valid way to introduce another term base.